# Characteristic functions in combinatorics.

Tags: combinatorics

I need to solve the following problem in combinatorics. How many pairs $(A_1,A_2)$ of subsets $\{1,2,...,n\}$ are there such that $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$?

The hint he give is to consider a $2$ by $n$ matrix for which the rows are the characteristic functions of $A_1$, respectively $A_2$. Translate the condition on $A_1$ and $A_2$ to a condition in this matrix.

I have the issue that I don't really understan what a characteristic function of $A_1$, could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: The answer is $3^n$. Hint: let $a_k = 1$ if $k\in A_1$, $a_k = 2$ if $k\in A_2$ and $a_k=0$ otherwise. This defines some one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic function of $A_1$ is the function

$$\mathbf{1}_{A_1}:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\{0,1\}$$

defined as follows: $\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(k)=1$ if $k\in A_1$, and $\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(k)=0$ if $k\notin A_1$. For example, if $n=10$, and $A_1=\{1,4,5,9\}$, then

$$\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(1)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(4)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(5)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(9)=1\;,$$

and

$$\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(2)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(3)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(6)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(7)=\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(8)=0\;.$$

We can represent this function in tabular form:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
k:&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(k):&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&0
\end{array}$$

The hint that you were given is to make a $2\times n$ array whose first row shows $\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(k)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$ and whose second row shows $\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(k)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. For instance, in my example I might take $A_2=\{2,7,10\}$, in which case the suggested matrix (with the rows labelled) would look like this:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc}
\mathbf{1}_{A_1}(k)&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&0&1&0\\
\mathbf{1}_{A_2}(k)&0&1&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1
\end{array}$$

Note that in any such array each column will have one of four forms: $0\atop 0$, $0\atop 1$, $1\atop 0$, and $1\atop 1$.

- Which of these are possible if $A_1\cap A_2=\varnothing$?
- Now think about picking $A_1$ and $A_2$ by filling in the matrix one column at a time. In how many ways can you do this so that $A_1\cap A_2=\varnothing$?

Comment: Thanks! The way I was thinking to solve would be to just set the characteristic function for $A_1$, which there would be $2^n$ possibilities there, then I would count the number of entries that have a $1$ in that row and let that number be i. Then, that would leave me with $2^{n-i}$possibilities for characteristic funtions $A_2$ such that $A_1 \cap A_2$. in the end, the total numer of such pairs would be $2^n*2^{n-i}.Would this be a right approach?

Comment: @Esteban: The problem with that is that you have to sum over all possible choices for $A_1$, and that’s going to get a bit messy. It’s better to consider the two sets simultaneously, by counting the legitimate ways to fill in the $n$ columns of that $2\times n$ matrix. How many choices are possible for each column?

Comment: I see, then in that case it would be just $3^n$, since only 3 combinations of columns $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$ satisfy the condition. Thanks!!

Comment: @Esteban: You’ve got it; you’re welcome!